# Find integral $\int^1_0 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx $ without antiderivative

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I don't think integrals are terrible when it comes to finding the antiderivative. But when I just can't do that, I get stuck. Can anyone show me how they'd solve this?

$$\int^1_0 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx $$

Comment: I think the question is getting at evaluating the integral by interpreting it as a region whose area is already known.

Answer (score 7):

This integral give us the area of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ lying in the first quadrant. So $$\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\mathrm d x=\frac{1}{4}\pi$$

Comment: How do you derive the area of a circle w/o integration?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, the greeks did it at least 2,000 years ago. For example, by approximation witn n-gons.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I would guess the intent is that the student "knows" the formula for the area of a circle, from having it dictated to them in elementary school without proof.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to find anti-derivative, Here's how

Substitute
$$x=\sin t\iff dx=\cos t\mathrm dt$$

$$$$

$$\begin{align}
I=\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm  dx\\
&=\int \sqrt{1-\sin^2t} \cos t\, \mathrm dt\\
&=\int \cos^2 t\, \mathrm dt\\
&=\int \frac{1+\cos 2t}{2}\,\mathrm  dt\\
&=\int \frac12\, \mathrm dt+\int\frac{\cos 2t}{2}\,\mathrm  dt\\
&=\frac{t}{2}+\frac{\sin 2t}{4}+C\\
&=\frac{2\arcsin(x)+2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{4}+C\\
&=\frac{\arcsin(x)+x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}+C\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2} dx=\left[\frac{\arcsin(x)+x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\right]_0^1=\frac\pi4$$